# Turn a list or data structure into an org document

Tags: org-mode

I'm writting a package which dowloads a list of healines, contents,
and some other properties, which are to be displayed to the user. For
the moment, an `org-mode` buffer seems like a good way of displaying
these headlines.

Below is an example of how this list might be structured. It is merely
illustrative, I can easily convert it to any other structure as
necessary.

```
'(("One headline" "Some much longer content."
   (property1 . value)
   (property2 . value))
  ("Second headline" "More much longer content."
   (property1 . value)
   (property2 . value)))
```

**Is there a function or package which prints such a list into an `org-mode` buffer?**

Here's the desired output.

```
* One headline
  :PROPERTIES:
  :property1: value
  :property2: value
  :END:
Some much longer content.

* Second headline
  :PROPERTIES:
  :property1: value
  :property2: value
  :END:
More much longer content.
```

I could do this manually, I'm just wondering if there might be
something out there.

Comment: Oh my, this would be very useful. +1.  I would note that even Org does so manually.  See `org-insert-drawer`.  (That is, I would imagine if such a converter existed, this function would call that one with `nil`.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the job of [`org-element`](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html), the *awesome*(!) work of **Nicolas Goaziou**.  If you don't know `org-element` and you care about org-development this is something you should look into.  It is not only a great tool to work with, it is also increasingly powering `org`.  Most notably the `org-export` ([`ox`](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Exporting)), but also functions in e.g. `org.el`.

To get the "lisp representation" of an element under point use `org-element-at-point` or `org-element-context`.  To get the representation of the buffer use `org-element-parse-buffer`.  While not directly relevant here, be aware of `org-element-map`.

To go from the "lisp representation" of an `element`, `secondary string` or `parse tree` back to the ["Org syntax representation"](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html) use `org-element-interpret-data`.  This is *the* (only) way to turn a "lisp representation" into a "Org syntax representation".  You will probably not want to write this representation manually, though.  Here's is a pretty small representation of your first headline

```
(org-element-interpret-data
 '(headline (:title "One headline" :level 1)
            (property-drawer nil ((node-property (:key "property1" :value "value1"))
                                  (node-property (:key "property2" :value "value2"))))
            (#("Some much longer content."))))
```

If you must add both headlines add a `parse tree`

```
(org-element-interpret-data
 '(org-data nil (headline (:title "One headline" :level 1)
                          (property-drawer nil ((node-property (:key "property1" :value "value1"))
                                                (node-property (:key "property2" :value "value2"))))
                          (#("Some much longer content.")))
            (headline (:title "Second headline" :level 1)
                          (property-drawer nil ((node-property (:key "property1" :value "value1"))
                                                (node-property (:key "property2" :value "value2"))))
                          (#("More much longer content.")))))
```

You may find that **Thorsten Jolitz**'s [`org-dp`](https://github.com/tj64/org-dp) library will aid you in such efforts ([on MELPA](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/104890)).

> The library `org-dp` is meant for programming at the local level,
>   i.e. without any (contextual) information except those about the
>   parsed element at point. It is designed to make using the Org
>   parser/interpreter framework at the local level as convenient as using
>   it at the global level (with a complete parse-tree produced by
>   `org-element-parse-buffer` available)

A more complete description by Thorsten can be found [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/104901).

For further clarifications [`gmane.emacs.orgmode`](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode) is really the appropriate forum.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I can't understand what org-dp brings beyond org-element.

Comment: `org-dp` is an alternative interface.  AFAIR, it was written to create documents in the Org syntax/format from an "elementy" point of view.  The goal of Org Element is to be a parser and a workhorse for Org.  I am personally just fine with `org-element`, but it's great to have alternative interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

I've sort of tangentially looked at this issue. Take a look at the [org-protocol.el](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html). It's bundled with org-mode. Specifically, the org-protocol-do-capture function converts a list, "parts" (which you seem to already have), to org-mode properties using org-store-link-props function and then calls org-capture. This assumes that you have a capture template with placeholders such as %:link. You can define the properties to be whatever you like.

I've done [something similar](https://github.com/sk8ingdom/.emacs.d/blob/master/org-mode-config/org-protocol-templates.el) to scrape title, author, date, source, etc. from site APIs. If you end up looking at this code, be sure to also look at capture-templates.el.

If you're working with JSON data, the json.el and / or request.el might be useful.